# dynamic add more combobox with different content

Tags: angularjs, combobox

I want to add more combo-box every time i click + button[image]

I

```js
    var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
    
app.controller('anotherOption',function($scope){
 $scope.options = [{name: "MakeUp"},{name: "PickUp"}];
 $scope.OptionItems=[{
  value:null
}];
$scope.duplicateOptionItem = function() {
  $scope.OptionItems.push({});
}
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<html ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="anotherOption">
          <select class="big_select" ng-model="OptionItem.value"  ng-repeat="OptionItem in OptionItems | limitTo: options.length">
            <option value="" disabled selected hidden>Items select</option>
            <option ng-repeat="option in options" value="{{ option.name }}">{{ option.name}}</option>
          </select>
          <button ng-click="duplicateOptionItem()">+</button>
```

I already can make it, but the thing is, i want to filter it, so every time i add more combo-box, it should show only the non-selected item.
Please help.. thankss

Goal:
when i choose Pick-Up in first combo-box and then click + button,
it should add more combo-box with only Make-Up options.

Comment: Please provide an example of what you wish to achieve

Comment: i already add my goal to my question.